# Linkedin Exchange JS API token for OAuth2 access token using node.js?

Tags: node.js, linkedin-jsapi

I need help for linkedin permanent token fetching.i  am using node.js.
 I'm able to successfully authenticate users, pass the secure cookie to my backend.
How  can  i exchange a JS API token for an OAuth1.0a access token.
tmpAcesstoken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'.verified signature also.
I tried  below method.

```
         oa = new OAuth( "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken",
                "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken",
                "xxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "1.0A", 
                "http://localhost:1337/", "HMAC-SHA1");


         oa.get("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth_oauth2_access_token="+tmpToken, function(error, data) {
                  if (error) {
                     console.log("error");
                      console.log(error);
                       } else {
                       console.log("success");
                        console.log(data);
                         }
                    });
```

this token is only valid for 60 days. how we can refresh token if user not visited for 60 days?

Please any one help to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens here is the reference how to exchange JS token to oauth 1.0a token.

I suppose you can't refresh token without interaction with user.